# Parsing XML syntax jQuery error

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing

In 46 string if I manually type name of point instead variable `res` [name of the point] it works. But if not, then won't work.

It works as:

1. Click on the point
2. Take name of the point
3. Search in Wikipedia
4. Parsing xml
5. Takes the URL from xml
6. Opens URL in iframe

**Where did I go wrong?**

[Pastebin code](http://pastebin.com/4reDinbb)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>

    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var map = null;

            function GetMap() {
                // Initialize the map
                map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), {
                    credentials: "An-KyHsPpYClz9oHXMZ6X3SW6I44Ei2DTTrUS_QlXUW43qqsvOAQrT9ekVEIBT9u"
                });
                Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'click', LatLong);
            }

            function LatLong(e) {
                if (e.targetType == "map") {
                    var point = new Microsoft.Maps.Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
                    var loc = e.target.tryPixelToLocation(point);
                    lola = "lo,loe".replace('lo', loc.latitude).replace('loe', loc.longitude);
                }
                MakeGeocodeRequest('An-KyHsPpYClz9oHXMZ6X3SW6I44Ei2DTTrUS_QlXUW43qqsvOAQrT9ekVEIBT9u');
            }

            function ClickGeocode(credentials) {
                map.getCredentials(MakeGeocodeRequest);
            }

            function MakeGeocodeRequest(credentials) {

                var geocodeRequest = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/" + lola + "/?output=json&jsonp=GeocodeCallback&key=" + credentials;
                CallRestService(geocodeRequest);
            }


            function GeocodeCallback(result) {
                res = (result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].name);
                console.log(res);
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&limit=1&format=xml&search="+res,
                        dataType: "xml",
                        success: xmlParser
                    });
                });
            }

            function xmlParser(xml) {
                var str = jQuery(xml).find("Url").text()
                alert(str);
                document.getElementById("iframe").src=str.replace('en.', 'm.');
            }


            function CallRestService(request) {
                var script = document.createElement("script");
                script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
                script.setAttribute("src", request);
                document.body.appendChild(script);
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="GetMap();">
        <iframe align="right" height="500px" id="iframe" src="" width="48%"></iframe>
        <div id='mapDiv' style="position:relative; width:48%; height:500px;"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Care to share what `console.log(res)` prints and what "does not work" actually means?

Comment: `console.log(res)` prints name of the point, to know what i am looking for in wiki. Does not work means that i am get empty `alert` instead url of town/place etc.

Comment: I suspect that "name of the point" contains a character that has a special meaning in URLs. Of course, we still don't know what `console.log(res)` prints because we only have a vague description of its output. And I've noticed you mention an error message but never share it with us. This questions is unanswerable because it omits important information.

Comment: For example, res equals `Wróblew, Woj. Lodzkie`, Poland. Then url `http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&limit=1&format=xml&search=Wróblew, Woj. Lodzkie` .Empty spaces will convert to special symbols and xml will ok, but if i using variable - res, it's not going.

Comment: `Console.log(res)` write to console `Wróblew, Woj. Lodzkie` (name of the point)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we basically have this:

```
function GeocodeCallback(result) {
    res = "Wróblew, Woj. Lodzkie";
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&limit=1&format=xml&search="+res,
            dataType: "xml",
            success: xmlParser
        });
    });
}
```

Main problems I can spot:

1. You are relying in a global `res` variable to feed the `url` in your AJAX call. This can easily fail if the browser attempts to perform two simultaneous AJAX requests. Have you missed the `var` keyword?
2. You can't inject random strings inside a URL. In vanilla JavaScript you'd use [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) but I'm sure jQuery allows to simply pass an object.

It might be unrelated to your problem (it's been impossible to get the exact error message from you) but it's my best guess.